# Wait for a trigger

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, wait, qwidget

I'm writing a PyQt application which needs to get some input before loading the main window. I have set up the following class (minimized):

```
class MyInput(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyInput, self).__init__()
        self.thing = False

        mybutton = QPushButton('Press me', self)
        mybutton.clicked.connect(self.set_data)

    def set_data(self):
        self.hide()
        self.destroyLater()
        self.thing = True

    def get_thing(self):
        self.show()
        return self.thing
```

Later, I have this function:

```
def ask_thing():
    mi = MyInput()
    return mi.get_thing()
```

Now, when I call `ask_thing()`, I want `mi.get_thing()` to wait for the button to be pressed before returning the value (or return False if it is closed). However, `self.show()` seems to run separately and lets the code continue executing, hitting the `return` statement and leaving the function.

How can I wait for input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have to consider changing from `QWidget` to `QDialog`. Then change the function `show` to `exec_`, which will execute the widget waiting user's interaction.

Comment: `QWidget` does not have an `exec` or `exec_` (because Python) function.

Comment: True. Maybe you should change to ``QDialog`` instead.